# Error con Modals en ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, modal

Tengo dos `modals` donde ingreso informacion, y en consecuente los ingreso a la base de datos con un `Button`, pero al momento de dar clic en el `Button` de uno o de otro, no hace ninguna accion, y observe que en los dos `modals` se marcan en rojo los inputs ya que los tengo como requeridos

Este es mi primer `modal`:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="user_Modal" role="dialog">
             <div class="modal-dialog">
                   <!-- Modal content-->
                     <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header" style="padding: 35px 50px;">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp Nuevo Usuario</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body" style="padding: 40px 50px;">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_who" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Who" AutoComplete="off" required="true"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <!-- /input-group -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="Span1"><i class="fa fa-universal-access" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                            <asp:TextBox required="true" ID="Txt_pay" onkeypress='validate(event)' runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Payroll Number" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <!-- /input-group -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="Span2"><i class="fa fa-child" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                            <asp:TextBox required="true" ID="Txt_name" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <!-- /input-group -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="Span3"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                            <asp:TextBox required="true" ID="Txt_ou" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="OU" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <!-- /input-group -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="Span4"><i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                            <asp:TextBox required="true" ID="Txt_pool" onkeypress='validate(event)' runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Pool" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <!-- /input-group -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="Span5"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                            <asp:TextBox required="true" ID="Txt_team" onkeypress='validate(event)' runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Team" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <!-- /input-group -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="Span6"><i class="fa fa-gavel" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                            <asp:TextBox required="true" ID="Txt_rol" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Rol" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <!-- /input-group -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="Span7"><i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                            <asp:TextBox type="password" required="true" ID="Txt_pass" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <!-- /input-group -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" class="btn btn-success" Text="Guardar" OnClick="Btn_submitData" />
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.row -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

y este es mi Segundo `modal`:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="tool_Modal">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">

                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header" style="padding: 35px 50px;">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4><i class="fa fa-cogs fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp New Tool</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body" style="padding: 40px 50px;">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-trademark" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_trade" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Trademark" AutoComplete="off" required="true"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <br />
                                        <!-- /input-group -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                                            <asp:TextBox required="true" ID="Txt_assign" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Name to assign" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <br />
                                        <!-- /input-group -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                            <asp:TextBox required="true" ID="Txt_min" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Torque min" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <br />
                                        <!-- /input-group -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                            <asp:TextBox required="true" ID="Txt_max" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Torque Max" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <br />
                                        <!-- /input-group -->
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-certificate " aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                            <asp:TextBox required="true" ID="Txt_status" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Status" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>

                                        <br />
                                        <!-- /input-group -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" class="btn btn-success" Text="Registrar" OnClick="tool_Submit" />
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.row -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si los modals van a ser dos validaciones diferentes, debes usar un elemento form en cada uno.

El botón submit lo que hace es validar los elementos del formulario, pero si tienes todos los modals dentro de un mismo formulario, todos los botones submit van a validar todos los campos.

Comment: de hecho ese debe ser mi error, no tengo ninguna etiqueta form, solo como los maestro arriba, lo checare

Comment: seguramente, si estás usando web forms de asp.net, debes tener un form, y no vas a poder tener dos froms con la prop runat=server.

Comment: por eso existen los objetos validadores de asp.net, quizás deberías usarlos en lugar de usar las validaciones de html5

Comment: objetos validadores?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwd43d0x.aspx

Comment: Tal vez mi pregunta suene tonta, pero... ¿tendria que hacer lo mismo que en php? me refiero a crear un archivo validacion.asp y en el hacer todo el procedimiento del insert y en el form en la parte de action direccionar a ese archivo?

Comment: nop. la validación la debes manejar con los validadores.

Comment: okok, gracias! leere lo que me compartiste y lo hare como me lo indicas

Comment: Que tal, me quedo una duda... ya cree los grupos a validar, y todos los inputs ya tienen su respective `RequiredFieldValidator` lo que ahora no se que sigue es con el boton, para que valide solo el uno de los grupos

Answer (score 0):

no debría guardarte nada, los campos los ves en rojo porque has definido "require" en el navegador, por lo que el navegador te dice que esa casilla no debe estar en blanco una vez des clic en el botón submit, pero no has definido un formulario, ni una acción, ni un método

Comment: Entonces deberia meter los `inputs` de cada `modal` en diferentes `forms`? cuando hace comentario un `modal` y el otro no, si me permite guarder los datos sin nignun problema, y tal vez yo estoy en lo incorrecto, tal vez no, pero la accion la declare en el `OnClick`